# Proof of accommodation for Thailand visa on arrival

Tags: visas, accommodation, thailand, itineraries, proof-of-accommodation

I am travelling to Thailand with some of my friends next week. I am an Indian national. I have two questions based on the checklist [here](http://www.suvarnabhumiairport.com/en/907-suvarnabhumi-visa-on-arrival)

- All our accommodation is booked in the name of one person. My name is nowhere in the hostel or hotel receipts. How do I show these receipts as a proof for my accommodation?
- The link says that I need a travel plan. Is it like a travel itinerary? Should I just write a document about the places I am visiting?

I have been told that getting Thailand visa is easy but, since all I have in travel history is two rejection stamps for Schengen visas, I am being more vigilant this time around.

Comment: Are you trying to get Visa on Arrival at the Thai airport?  Or a SETV at the Thai Embassy in India first?  Will you all be traveling together?  I think the VoA isn't as strict.

Comment: I am traying for a VoA at Bangkok airport. We are a group of five and four of us will be travelling together. The booking for the first two days is in the name of the person travelling alone. He'll reach Thailand before us

Comment: You may have a bit a problem, as the person with the accommodation proof is travelling separately and before the four of you do. Note that the proof and travel plan are part of the interview, and issues during that process could affect your holiday plans.

Answer (score 2):

> All our accommodation is booked in the name of one person. My name is
>   nowhere in the hostel or hotel receipts. How do I show these receipts
>   as a proof for my accommodation?

Unfortunately this means you do not have **proof** of accommodation. You can show his proof of accommodation and your communication (emails, for example) where he promises to accommodate you. However technically this is not proof - because he could have sent the same email to twenty other people, or could have sent you a follow-up saying that he's not going. Immigration has no way to check any of those, and they require "*Truthfully notify the verifiable places to stay in Thailand*" as part of qualification for VOA.

Also consider the possibilities: what if this person holding the accommodation is denied entry to Thailand? What if he/she gets into accident on their way to hotel? This would leave you stranded.

> The link says that I need a travel plan. Is it like a travel itinerary? Should I just write a document about the places I am visiting?

Travel plan is more like an overview of what you're going to do and where - and of course it should match your proof of accommodation and other evidence. For example if you plan to stay 3 days in Bangkok and 3 days in Phuket, you may be asked to show tickets to Phuket and hotel reservations there.  Tourists visiting a country usually have at least vague idea how they'd be spending time there and where. There is no need to provide a timesheet document with exact dates and times, or any document at all - but you must be able to answer questions about how you are going to spend your time in Thailand, and match it with other evidence.

Comment: I think some of you guys are over-reacting.  Technically.  But if you are traveling together it should not be a problem.  If you are not, it is unlikely to be a problem.  Especially if you have never been to Thailand before or only come a couple of times a year.

Comment: @JonGrah better be safe then sorry when dealing with Immigration.

Answer (score 1):

You can show any accommodation address for your first night and no one will check whether you booked it or not. If you're really afraid of this, you can book cheapest option for a few bucks to show it as proof and cancel it later.

I have applied for visa on arrival at Krabi airport, process was quick and smooth, there were no questions about my travel plan or if I have required cash amount. For a quicker application, I would advise you to exchange Thailand baht in advance and have photo. It may not be exchange office or ATM before visa application stand. If you pay by USD or EUR, they may charge more.